# Playing sound on app startup

Tags: java, android

How do I go about getting my app to play an mp3 (in my res) on startup? Or how how about if I wanted this to happen when a button is clicked?

Comment: first make sure your users really want your app to play sounds on startup, or at least add an option to disable it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Audio and Video section of the [Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html):

> Perhaps the most common thing to want
>   to do is play back media (notably
>   sound) within your own applications.
>   Doing this is easy:
>
> 1. Put the sound (or other media resource) file into the res/raw folder of your project,
>      where the Eclipse plugin (or aapt) will find it and make it into a resource that can be
>      referenced from your R class
> 2. Create an instance of MediaPlayer, referencing that resource using MediaPlayer.create, > and then call start() on the instance:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mp.start();
```

> To stop playback, call stop(). If you
>   wish to later replay the media, then
>   you must reset() and prepare() the
>   MediaPlayer object before calling
>   start() again. (create() calls
>   prepare() the first time.)
>
> To pause playback, call pause().
>   Resume playback from where you paused
>   with start().

So put the above code example in the onCreate() or onStart() of your launcher activity to have it play on startup, and place it in a button's onClick() method to respond to a button press.

Comment: my app plays the sound but not till the end - it stops before.